# fail to create operation with c8yDeviceControl.creat

Tags: cumulocity

I'm new to cumulocity application development. Now I'm learning to use Smart App Toolkit to develop HTML5 application.
I could create device in my Tenant, and could run some operations with servces provided in the SDK. However, I failed to create operation with `c8yDeviceControl.create()`. I got `400 (bad request) error code` after the operation, and if I look deeper with chrome develop tool, it shows

> {error: "Failed to parse JSON string"},

Here is my code, which I pick up from the Smart SDK sample code, with modifition to reference my `deviceId`:

```
var operation = {
                  deviceId: 12111,
                  com_cumulocity_model_WebCamDevice: {
                      name: 'take picture',
                      parameters: {
                          duration: '5s',
                          quality: 'HD'
                      }
                  }
              };
              c8yDeviceControl.create(operation);
```

Could anyone provide me a help to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `deviceID` needs to be a string. This works:

```
var operation = {
                  deviceId: '1211',
                  com_cumulocity_model_WebCamDevice: {
                      name: 'take picture',
                      parameters: {
                          duration: '5s',
                          quality: 'HD'
                      }
                  }
              };
              c8yDeviceControl.create(operation);
```

Sorry for the inconvenience, we'll update the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick respone. it works, I could create an operation in the cumulocity server, but  in the meantime,  there are some error messages release my chrome browser. Right now, I setup the app from localhost, and run the app from chrome browser on same PC. Here are the logs from chrome browser:

Comment: angular.js:9997 TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
    at k (deviceControl.js:267)
    at wrappedCallback (angular.js:11498)
    at wrappedCallback (angular.js:11498)
    at angular.js:11584
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:12608)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:12420)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12712)
    at done (angular.js:8315)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:8527)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8466)

Comment: Could you write a new question with your issue? It makes it easier to respond to, especially if others want to dive in. Also, please the response of the operation.

Comment: OK, I just wirte a new question about the issue.